# embedded linux - running from uncompressed image

Tags: kernel, embedded-linux

On embedded systems, it seems like the common thing to do is decompress the kernel and then launch.
Aside from the extra flash required to hold the uncompressed image - If i grabbed a embedded linux project and wanted to mod it to not store the kernel compressed, is there anything I need to know about that might be considered tricky?

Comment: I think you're referring to Flash memory as in a non-volatile computer storage / EEPROM, and not Adobe Flash as you have tagged.

Comment: Specifically, OP might be referring to NOR-Flash, as only NOR has XIP support.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really good explanation of how to do this on ARM here:
http://free-electrons.com/blog/uncompressed-linux-kernel-on-arm/

The tricky part is that the ARM Linux config doesn't provide an uncompressed kernel option.  However, you can generate the uncompressed image from arch/arm/boot/Image manually.